# why sonarlint shows different issues than sonarqube server

Tags: sonarqube, sonarlint, sonarlint-intellij

I have connected intellij sonarlint with sonarqube server successfully as discripted here:

```
File -> Settings -> Other Settings -> SonarLint General Settings
Click on the green + in "SonarQube servers" :
    Enter a name (ex : SonarQube / localhost)
    Select SonarQube and enter URL like http://localhost:9000
    Authentication : select your user token or your login/pwd
    Click on Finish
    Click on "Update binding" to synchronize with the SonarQube server
Go to SonarLint Project Settings and bind your project to the SonarQube project
```

when I analyize one java file with sonarlint, it display different issues than I can see in the same file on the sonarqube server.

I have used "update binding" and nothing change. Any Idea, why sonarlint shows different issues than sonarqube server?

Comment: Could you give us at least one example? What SonarQube version do you use?

Comment: I have installed plugin sonarlint Version: 3.4.2.2586 in intellij

Comment: Please add screens of the code with issues (SonarLint and SonarQube server).

Comment: Not all plugins are supported by SonarLint, posting all installed analyzer plugins on the SonarQube server will help to spot incompatible plugins.

Comment: I have the same issue. In SonarQube rule `fb-contrib:CLI_CONSTANT_LIST_INDEX` is applied, in SonarLint not.